# Are member functions part of a structure in memory?

Tags: c#, memory

I am working on a networking application in C# for which I need to transfer a structure (It contains 3 string members).

I would also like to include member functions that test those 3 strings for validity in certain ways.

I am wondering, if I were to convert that structure (I use Marshal.StructToPtr) to bytes in order to send it over a connection, would it just convert the member variables (the 3 strings) or every function too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application code (the IL instructions, methods, machine code, etc) is not part of any serialization process. It will only serialize the data (the fields) in there.

You can view memory as different segments where class/struct definitions are separated from the instance data.

*It is a bad practice to send code over the wire for serialization purposes since it opens the remote process for executing arbitrary code.*

Comment: What do you mean by application code. The functions are part of the structure. You mean that the functions will not be converted and just the rest of the data (the strings)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro!